# Trying to render image from grayscale camera with OpenCV in C++. Hangs after a few frames

Tags: raspbian, opencv, c++

have a grayscale camera (NOT COLOR) and am trying to render the image. I am running on Raspbian, on a Raspberry Pi 2. I've grabbed some code and bared it to a minimum and made some progress:

```
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include <iostream>
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

    int main(int, char**)
    {
        VideoCapture cap(0); // open the default camera
        if(!cap.isOpened())  // check if we succeeded
            return -1;
        bool rtn;
        rtn = cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH , 752);  //returns 0
        cout << "set to 752:" << rtn << endl;
        rtn = cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT , 480);  //returns 0
        cout << "set to 480:" << rtn << endl;
        int count = 1;
        Mat edges;
        namedWindow("edges",1);
        for(;;)
        {
            Mat frame;
            cap >> frame; // get a new frame from camera
            cout << "cols:" <<frame.cols << endl;
            cout << "rows:" << frame.rows << endl;
            cout << "count:" << count++ << endl;
            cout << "Channel Count:"<< frame.channels() << endl; // returns 3
            cvtColor(frame, edges, CV_BGR2GRAY);
            imshow("edges", edges);
            if(waitKey(30) >= 0) break;
        }
        // the camera will be deinitialized automatically in VideoCapture destructor
        return 0;
    }
```

Now I get grayscale image, but it only runs for a few (2-4, it varies) frames, then hangs. Interestingly, if you wait long enough, sometimes it will scan a few more frames after "select timeout" messages.

I have tried running the following before running the application but it doesn't seem to help:

```
rmmod uvcvideo
modprobe uvcvideo nodrop=1 timeout=5000
```

The camera specification is 752x480 (leopardimaging.com/LI-USB30-V034.html)
Even though I specify the camera resolution as 720x480 (per the camera spec), it reports the frame size as 640x480.

Note that:

```
frame.channels() << endl; // returns 3
cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH , 752); //returns 0
cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT , 480);  //returns 0
```

Here is another (more simple) attempt:

```
int main(int, char**) {
  VideoCapture cap(0); // open the default camera
  if (!cap.isOpened()) // check if we succeeded
    return -1;
  //bool rtn;
  //rtn = cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 752);
  //cout << "set to 752:" << rtn << endl;
  //rtn = cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 480);
  //cout << "set to 480:" << rtn << endl;
  int count = 1;
  Mat edges;
  namedWindow("edges", 1);
  Mat frame;
  for (;;) {
    cap >> frame; // get a new frame from camera
    if (count == 1) {
      cout << "cols:" << frame.cols << endl;
      cout << "rows:" << frame.rows << endl;
      cout << "Channel Count:" << frame.channels() << endl;
    }
    cout << "count:" << count++ << endl;
    imshow("edges", frame);
    if (waitKey(1) >= 0) break;
  }
  // the camera will be deinitialized automatically in VideoCapture destructor
  return 0;
}
```

When it runs, it displays a couple (2-10) of frames, then I get "select timeout" messages.  It only advances through the loop, it doesn't update the image.

Comment: I've seen others with similar issues, but never resolved.  Surely someone is doing this?

Comment: Surely someone has solved this in the past?